# How to Convert GMUFeature to GMSPath

Tags: ios, swift

I have drawn slots on google maps using Geojson. Now when the user long presses on the slot should ask the user whether to save the location or not. But I don't know how to enable long press only for the slots. Could anybody suggest me how to do this. Below is the code I have used.

```
`// the below is the code to render the slots on the google maps 
let geoJsonParser = GMUGeoJSONParser(url: url!)
geoJsonParser.parse()
let renderer = GMUGeometryRenderer(map: self.mapview, geometries: geoJsonParser.features)
let style = GMUStyle(styleID: "random", stroke: UIColor.black, fill: UIColor.green, width: 2, scale: 1, heading: 0, anchor: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), iconUrl: nil, title: nil, hasFill: true, hasStroke: true)

for feature in geoJsonParser.features {
        feature.style = style
   }
   renderer.render()

// The below code is to check whether the user has long pressed on the slot or not(written this code inside the didLongPressAt function).

for feature in geoJsonParser.features {
            if GMSGeometryContainsLocation(coordinate, feature as! GMSPath, true) {// the app is crashing with an error in the console "Could not cast value of type 'GMUFeature' (0x1033573d0) to 'GMSPath' (0x1033585a0)"
                print("YES: you are in this polygon.")
                marker.title = "\(coordinate)"
                marker.map = mapview
            } else {
                print("You do not appear to be in this polygon.")
            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after lot of efforts I found the solution.

**Note:** If anyone is integrating Google-Maps-iOS-Utils library, then don't add header files in Bridging-Header file as suggested in Google developer document.
Wherever you are using the below code, just write **import GoogleMapsUtils** at top.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "dld_areas", ofType: "json")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let data: Data = try! Data.init(contentsOf: url)
    let json = try JSON(data: data)
    //our json is having properties containing area name and area id, bacause the properties field inside the GMUFeature is retuning us nil, we have to pass it indiviually
    let jsonFeatures: [JSON] = json["features"].array ?? []

    geoJsonParser = GMUGeoJSONParser.init(data: data)
    geoJsonParser.parse()

    var index = 0

    for feature in geoJsonParser.features {


        var innerFeature = feature
        while(innerFeature.geometry.type != "GeometryCollection"){
            print("type is" + innerFeature.geometry.type)

            innerFeature = innerFeature.geometry as! GMUGeometryContainer

        }

        let collection = innerFeature.geometry as! GMUGeometryCollection

        let polygon:GMUPolygon = collection.geometries.first as! GMUPolygon
        var isAreaObtained = false

        for path in polygon.paths{

            //check if the coordinates lie within the polygon
            if (GMSGeometryContainsLocation(coordinates, path, true)) {

                isAreaObtained = true
                print(jsonFeatures[index]["properties"]["NAME_EN"])
                print(jsonFeatures[index]["properties"]["AREA_ID"])

                print("location inside polygon")
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isAreaObtained){
            break
        }

        index = index + 1
    }
```

I found the above code in the following link:
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/205
I have used this code and modified as per my requirement.

Comment: I used this one. it works on some polygons but some doesnt work. google needs to provide a mapview for GMUFeature or at least have some way to get a reference of the GMSOverlay when clicked and return the GMUfeature assoiated with it.